# How does one install etcd in a cluster?

Tags: etcd

Newbie w/ etcd/zookeeper type services ...

I'm not quite sure how to handle cluster installation for etcd. Should the service be installed on each client or a group of independent servers? I ask because if I'm on a client, how would I query the cluster? Every tutorial I've read shows a curl command running against localhost.

Answer (score 0):

For `etcd` cluster installation, you can install the service on independent servers and form a cluster. The cluster information can be queried by logging onto one of the machines and running curl or remotely by specifying the IP address of one of the cluster member node.

For more information on how to set it up, [follow this article](http://blog.redpelicans.com/how-to-hot-deploy-containers-thanks-to-docker-swarm-and-overlay-network/)